# Maven clean compile does not work

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

I have maven-compiler-plugin in my pom file as follows but compiler get angry with generic parameters. my maven version is "Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 19:31:09+0200)"

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and the class which compiler get angry is as follows

```
List<EulTransactionHistory> list = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria, -1, 1);
EulTransactionHistory existingRecord = DBUtils.oneAndOnlyOne(list);
```

and the spec for DBUtils.oneAndOnlyOne is as follows

```
public static <T> T oneAndOnlyOne(List<T> list) {...}
```

finally the exception is

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project etlscheduler: Compilation failure: Compilation failure SchedulerDaoImpl.java:[329,18] incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: com.aric.etlscheduler.domain.EulTransactionHistory
```

Moreover when I compile this project with eclipse it compiles sucessfully.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of DBUtils or the spring stuff in your classpath? They might be loaded in a different order by Eclipse and Maven.

Answer (score 0):

The jar containing the `com.aric.etlscheduler.domain.EulTransactionHistory` class is missing from the classpath of your project. Make sure you have added the jar as dependency in your project's pom.

Comment: it is in there, it is not a dependency, it is in my source and is ofcourse in the classpath

Comment: by the way it is compiled successfully with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler error, it looks like this is possibly what is happening.

- `DBUtils.oneAndOnlyOne(list)` is returning `Object` instead of `EulTransactionHistory`.
- This is because the list which is passed to the method is a list of `Objects` and not a list of `EulTransactionHistory`.
- This, in turn, is because `hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria()` is returning a list of `Objects` and not a list of `EulTransactionHistory`.

Comment: I don t think that I have any problem with the syntax, because it is compiled successfully with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If line 329 is

```
EulTransactionHistory existingRecord = DBUtils.oneAndOnlyOne(list);
```

then it's because 1) your Maven classpath's first DBUtils class has a oneAndOnlyOne() method that returns java.lang.Object, or 2) you're not passing it the list you think you're passing it, but an unparameterized List or a List.

Answer (score 0):

Is DBUtils in a different project, and did you at one time have a DBUtils.oneAndOnlyOne() that returned an Object?  If so, you need to do a Maven install on that project.

Maven uses the last-installed jar, while Eclipse, assuming you set it up in the usual way, is snooping directly into the other project.